# AuthorizeAttribute filter setting returnUrl for my login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

Everything is working great; however, the bug I found in my system is the following.

1. The user is logged in the system correctly and browsing the options.
2. The session expires while the user is in a given view. That view has a button that posts to a Partial View (which again, returns a partial view).
3. Once the user click the button, the AuthorizeAttribute sends him/her back to the Login page with a given returnUrl="xxx/yyy/zzz" value.
4. The user logs in again, and is redirected correctly to the partial view.

My question is the following. Since the user is redirected to a partial view, he/she is not able to see the entire page (the menu, footer, etc. -> master page stuff).

How can I easily check if the returnUrl belongs to a Partial View or not, because in that case I will probably just redirect the user to the /Home/Index.

Answer (score 1):

First in partial view request action set `ReturnUrl`:

```
public ActionResult ReturnPartialView ()
{
   if (Request != null && Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
      ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Action", "Controller");
      .
      .
      .
   }
   return null;
}
```

and finally in partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And if you looking for more effective way to handle this problem you should override Authorize Attribute and here is some links can guide you.

[Handling authentication-specific issues for AJAX-calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655086/Handling-authentication-specific-issues-for-AJAX-c)

[How do you deal with authorisation on actions that return results other than ViewResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472610/how-do-you-deal-with-authorisation-on-actions-that-return-results-other-than-view)

[ASP.NET MVC redirect to login page with AJAX](http://dotscrapbook.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-login-page-with-ajax/)

Comment: thank you Mohsen! I'll give it a try. However, since this is a large system and I don't want to force every developer to "remember" this for every single partialview I'm looking for a more "general" solution...... But I'll try anyhow, this could be very helpful.